# How to add shipping cost to the cart total in Gloudemans Shoppingcart using Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel

I want the result for `Cart::subtotal() + $order->shipping;`

This is the error message I am getting:

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Comment: dd(Cart::subtotal(), $order->shipping); 
add this info to question

Comment: these is the result: "7,400.00" "500"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
str_replace(',', '', Cart::subtotal()) + $order->shipping;
```

Answer (score -1):

₦{{ number_format((str_replace(',', '', Cart::total()) + $shippingRate),2)}} I introduce number format to return the , (comma) 0n the total

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).